# Is this way of passing and modifying a hashmap threadsafe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

This is a little piece of code

```
public Map<String,Object> findTruckParts(Map<String,Object> output){
Map<String,Object>findPartsMap = null;
NewFooInstance newFooInstance = new NewFooInstance();
findPartsMap = PartBuilder.buildPartsOutputMap(output, outputMap);
newFooInstance.buildItem(findPartsMap);
return findPartsMap;
}
```

outputMap is a new hashMap and output is a hashmap with some spare parts info.
buildItem calls a few other private methods passing around the findPartsMap.

```
public class NewFooInstance{
buildItem(Map<String,Object> partsMap){
checkPartsValidity(partsMap, fetchMapOfValidParts());
}

checkPartsValidity(Map<String,Object> partsMap,Map<String,Object> partsMap){
//partsMap = update partsMap with missing items fetched from list of valid parts
}
}
```

Is the above thread safe ? Since all the maps are local to the respective methods, My assumption is that this is thread safe. 

**Edit**: I have modified the method a little bit. Takes in a map and returns another one. So, my question is, is this map that is being returned be thread safe? It is local to the method so I think this is going to be threadsafe (no other thread entering will be able to change its value in case this map loses its monitor), however, since this map is being modified in other classes and other methods, does this method-localness of this map carry over across different classes/methods and assure thread safety ?

Comment: All single-threaded code is thread-safe.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, sure it is :) My question was whether the above snippet that I posted be thread safe in a multi threaded env ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure. And the Object being passed in to different methods, where it is altered (just not declared), is also going to be thread safe ?

Comment: And what exactly do you have in mind with "multi threaded env"? Other threads hanging around, doing their stuff? You must indicate precisely what threads you are involving and where.

Comment: One thing I can tell you about your little piece of code is that the `= new HashMap<String,Ojbect>();` part makes no sense. You should delete that.

Comment: Thread safety issues arise when you share state across threads. What instance/class variables do you share? How do you access them?

Comment: I have edited my question, to be a better question.

Comment: Are `PartBuilder.buildPartsOutputMap(output, outputMap)` and `newFooInstance.buildItem(findPartsMap)` thread-safe?

Comment: @EJP 'PartBuilder.buildPartsOutputMap(output, outputMap)' is thread safe, I am not sure about buildItems. I have edited some code above to show the newFooInstance class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "no", because `HashMap` itself is not threadsafe.

Consider using a threadsafe Map implementation such as [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: sure it isnt. But then when every thread has its own stack of method local Objects, I wonder if there will ever be a HashMap declared in a method that will not be threadsafe. Isn't ConcurrentHashMap to be used in situations where the state of a hashmap is being altered in different places in the same class ?

Comment: A) if an instance of your class is referenced from multiple threads, you're sunk. B) ConcurrentHashMap is used when modifying in one thread and reading or writing in another.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
public Map<String,Object> findTruckParts(Map<String,Object> output)
```

Even though things look thread-safe in the methods and sub-methods with respect to resulting map, you still have a thread safety issue with the source map (i.e. 'output'). As you extract data from it to put into the new resulting map, if it is altered by another thread at the same time, you will get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Below is some code to illustrate the issue:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, Object> test = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread 1: started");
        findTruckParts(test);
        System.out.println("Thread 1: done");
      }

      public Map<String,Object> findTruckParts(Map<String,Object> output) {
        Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
          for(String key : output.keySet()) {
            result.put("x", output.get(key));
          }
        }

        return result;
      }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread 2: started");

        for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
          test.put("y", "y"+i);
          test.remove("y");
        }

        System.out.println("Thread 2: done");
      }
    }).start();
  }

}
```

And the output is invariably:

> Thread 1: started Thread 2: started Exception in thread "Thread-1"
>   java.util.ConcurrentModificationException     at
>   java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:793)    at
>   java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:828)  at
>   Test$1.findTruckParts(Test.java:19)   at Test$1.run(Test.java:12)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) Thread 2: done

So even though the `findTruckParts()` method creates its own map to return, if it has to look into the source map and some other thread is modifying its keys/values, there will be a problem. The the other threads are only reading, it shouldn't blow up. But I'm not sure you want to talk about thread safety in this case because it's still precarious.

One way to help with thread safety is to change the first line of the `main` method with:

```
final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> test = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>(new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

But you can see how safety requirement is pushed on to the caller, which isn't great. So to help that, you could also alter the signature of the method:

```
public Map<String,Object> findTruckParts(ConcurrentHashMap<String,Object> output);
```

And now there is thread safety.

Therefore, as I stated on the first line, the problem is here:

The problem is here:

```
public Map<String,Object> findTruckParts(Map<String,Object> output)
```

I hope this helps.